# Integral identity with Laplace operator

Tags: probability, analysis

Let $p(t,x) := \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} $ (the density of the normal distribution) and let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable with compact support.

Let $t>0$. Show

$$\int p(t,x) f''(x) dx = \int f(x) \frac{dp}{dt}(t,x)dx$$

I don't know how to show this. My idea is that it has something to do with the convolution.

Comment: The specification "with compact support" leads me to believe that you are not looking to evaluate an indefinite integral, but are instead looking to integrate over all space. In that case, you can use integration by parts to get $f''(x)$ to $f(x)$ and then compare $\frac{\text{d}^2p}{\text{d}x^2}$ with $\frac{\text{d}p}{\text{d}{t}}$. The terms not under an integral would go to zero because $f(x)$ and its derivatives must be zero as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$. Unfortunately, this equality requires a constant multiple of $2$ on the right hand side, but it is very close.

Comment: Perhaps you know more about the bounds or $f(x)$ than the question indicates, but I would suggest trying integration by parts.